# Using AutoComplete plugin on multiple textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have a plugin of auto complete which takes 3 parameters

```
    $(function(){
    setAutoComplete("id", "results", "url");
});
```

Now i am trying to use it on multiple text boxes where there are different urls to fetch data from but its not working. if i use it on a single text box its working.
I have done this in javascript

```
$(function(){
    setAutoComplete("searchField1", "results", "url1");
});
$(function(){
    setAutoComplete("searchField2", "results", "url2");
});
$(function(){
    setAutoComplete("searchField3", "results", "url3");
});
```

But still it is not working.
Help required.

Comment: _"...its not working"_ isn't enough.  Does the `setAutoComplete` function properly allow for multiple elements? Use firebug and check for errors in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple functions try this.
Assign a class to all the input fields on which you want autocomplete to appear. LEt say the class name is autocomplete.
Then use a single function

```
$(function()
{
    $('.autocomplete').click(function()// or focus or keyperess
    {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if(id == 'color'){
       setAutoComplete( id, "results", "url");
    }else if(id == 'name'){
       setAutoComplete( id, "results", "another url");
    }else if(id == 'blah blah'){
       setAutoComplete( id, "results", "blah blah url");
    }
     });
});
```